# Taxes in one query (cumulative or regular taxes)

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from phppos_sales_items_taxes;
+---------+---------+------+-------+---------+------------+
| sale_id | item_id | line | name  | percent | cumulative |
+---------+---------+------+-------+---------+------------+
|       1 |       1 |    1 | Tax 1 |   10.00 |          0 |
|       1 |       1 |    1 | Tax 2 |   10.00 |          1 |
|       3 |       1 |    1 | Tax 1 |   10.00 |          0 |
|       3 |       1 |    1 | Tax 2 |   10.00 |          0 |
|       4 |       1 |    1 | Tax 1 |    8.00 |          0 |
|       4 |       1 |    1 | Tax 2 |   10.00 |          1 |
+---------+---------+------+-------+---------+------------+

mysql> select * from phppos_sales_items;
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| sale_id | item_id | description | serialnumber | line | quantity_purchased | item_cost_price | item_unit_price | discount_percent |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
|       1 |       1 |             |              |    1 |               1.00 |            8.00 |           10.00 |                0 |
|       3 |       1 |             |              |    1 |               1.00 |            8.00 |           10.00 |                0 |
|       4 |       1 |             |              |    1 |               3.00 |            8.00 |           10.00 |                0 |
|       5 |       2 |             |              |    1 |               1.00 |           10.00 |           12.00 |                0 |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now for each percent (10.00, 8.00 etc), I need to determine the total tax in one query. If the tax has cumulative = 1, then the tax is determined by (subtotal + other tax in sale) * tax_percent / 100 otherwise it is the standard tax formula.

```
SELECT percent, 
       SUM(subtotal) AS subtotal, 
       SUM(total)    AS total, 
       SUM(tax)      AS tax 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               Concat(percent, '%') 
               AS 
                      PERCENT, 
               ( item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - 
                 item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * 
                 discount_percent / 100 ) AS subtotal, 
               IF (cumulative = 1, Round(( item_unit_price * quantity_purchased 
                                           - 
                                           item_unit_price * quantity_purchased 
                                           * 
                                           discount_percent / 100 + 
--NEED TO DO A SUBQUERY HERE TO GET SALES TAX FOR FOR SALE_ID, ITEM_ID, LINE


 ) * ( 
                                                             percent / 100 ), 2) 
               , Round 
               (( 
               item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - 
               item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * 
               discount_percent 
               / 100 ) * ( 1 + ( percent / 100 ) ), 2)) 
               AS 
                      total, 
               Round(( item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - 
                       item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * 
                             discount_percent / 100 ) * 
                     ( percent / 100 ), 2) 
               AS tax 
        FROM   phppos_sales_items_taxes 
               JOIN phppos_sales_items 
                 ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id = 
                    phppos_sales_items_taxes.sale_id 
                    AND phppos_sales_items.item_id = 
                        phppos_sales_items_taxes.item_id 
                    AND phppos_sales_items.line = phppos_sales_items_taxes.line 
               JOIN phppos_sales 
                 ON phppos_sales_items_taxes.sale_id = phppos_sales.sale_id 
        WHERE  phppos_sales.deleted = 0 
               AND DATE(sale_time) BETWEEN '2011-07-28' AND '2011-07-28') AS 
       temp_taxes 
GROUP  BY percent
```

Comment: To make this clearer, can you show (by hand) the calculation you want to perform?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `IF` statement:

```
IF(cumulative = 1,(((subtotal+other_tax_in_sale)* tax_percent) / 100), standard_tax)
```

This should work if you fill in the values.

Comment: The problem I am having with this is is "other_tax_in_sale" I can't seem to figure out how to do a subquery for it. I have updated my post with there I am stuck.